# Stop external user from uploading viruses to server

Tags: security, malware, virus

I am making a site that enables external users to upload files to a server. Then other users will be able to download these files. I have done some research into how to prevent users uploading [image] and [image: malware], and I have drawn the following conclusions:

- Clam AV can be used in order to scan for [image] on a server
- Add a 'report' button on the download page on the website
- Create multiple backups in the case the system get infected
- Quality assure all files that have been uploaded by the external user

Is there anything else that I can do in order to prevent an external users from uploading viruses to a site?

Can Clam AV been used to detect Windows and Mac [image]?

Can Clam AV be installed on an external server owned by a host? Or do I need a dedicated server?

Thanks - highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Clam AV you can use eScan Antivirus which easily detects Windows, Linux and Mac based malwares and Viruses.
eScan Antivirus company can also provide you the SDK to integrate with your services. So that if you want to scan any file and get the result back with
 name of virus if any this Software Development Kit will be most helpful to you. eScan also provide services for all operating system platforms.

For load balancing you can keep your AntiVirus service on other dedicated server.

For more information you can contact eScan Antivirus at http://www.escanav.com/.

Thanks.